# How can I print the Layout builder in a node twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

After enabling Layout builder for Page content. I can see in Manage fields, a new field called layout_builder__layout. I want to print this inside node--page twig template. This should work but it does not. `{{ content.layout_builder__layout }}`. Printing all the content does display it like this `{{ content }}` How can I print only the layout builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Layout builder` and `Manage fields` (moving fields inside Manage Display) are mutually exclusive, you use either the first or the second, you can not mix them. As soon as you activate Layout Builder for a node type, the entire Twig render array is only the Layout builder.

So just render `{{ content }}`, which renders its one and only child `{{ content._layout_builder }}`

Comment: Thank you @hudri

Comment: @hudri suppose I have enabled layout builder for a content type but one one particular node I want to do something different -   so I can no longer use {{ content.body }} in the node's twig template ie it renders nothing?

Comment: No you can't. You could create a `node--NUMERIC_ID.html.twig` overwrite template, and use manually, hard-coded twig in that template to render your fields, e.g. `<div class="my_class">{{ node.field_XXX.0.value }}</div>` etc.

Comment: In order to print just a Node field somewhere on the page you can also use the [fieldblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldblock) module.